# How to read a hdf5 file without knowing the database name in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hdf5

I have a hdf5 database but almost no experience with that kind of database. I need to open / load it in Matlab. However the Matlab function `h5read` requires two arguments

```
data = h5read(filename,dataset)
```

I know my Filename (obviously :) ) but I don't know the dataset name (because I cannot look into the hdf5 databse).

Does anyone know how to find out the dataset names in a hdf5 database?

Comment: You can use the hdf5info function to determine the names of data sets in an HDF5 file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Mathworks](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hdf5info.html), you can use `h5info`(or the deprecated `hdf5info`) to get the name of the datasets inside a hdf5 database

```
fileinfo = hdf5info(filename);

toplevel = fileinfo.GroupHierarchy
```

Gives:

```
  toplevel = 

  Filename: [1x64 char]
      Name: '/'
    Groups: [1x2 struct]
  Datasets: []
 Datatypes: []
     Links: []
Attributes: [1x2 struct]
```

Comment: Ahh ok. That was easy :). Thanks a lot